# Kafka Sink Connector for Cassandra failed

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka

I'm creating Kafka Sink Conector for Cassandra via Lenses. My configuration is:

```
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
connect.cassandra.key.space=space1
connect.cassandra.contact.points=cassandra1
tasks.max=1
topics=demo-1206-enriched-clicks-v0.1
connect.cassandra.port=9042
connect.cassandra.kcql=INSERT INTO space1.CLicks_Test SELECT ClicksId from demo-1206-enriched-clicks-v0.1
name=test_cassandra
```

but, I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Mandatory `topics` configuration contains topics not set in connect.cassandra.kcql: Set(demo-1206-enriched-clicks-v0.1)
at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.config.Helpers$.checkInputTopics(Helpers.scala:107)
at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector.start(CassandraSinkConnector.scala:65)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:100)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:125)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.transitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:182)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startConnector(Worker.java:210)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startConnector(DistributedHerder.java:872)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.processConnectorConfigUpdates(DistributedHerder.java:324)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.tick(DistributedHerder.java:296)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:199)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm suspecting that topic name could be issue - can you change it to something simple?

Comment: Yes, the problem is in dot (.) in the topic name. When I exclude it everything works fine, but I would like to keep it.

Comment: For me it looks like a bug in KSQL parser...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jelena, as discussed already the problem is with Kafka Connect  framework not being able to parse `.1` in `topics=demo-1206-enriched-clicks-v0.1`. A bug should be reported to Kafka GitHub.

@Alex what you see there is *Not* KSQL. The configuration SQL we use for all our connectors is KCQL(Kafka connect query language).

Furthermore we have our equivalent SQL for Apache Kafka.called LSQL: http://www.landoop.com/docs/lenses/

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed at https://launchpass.com/datamountaineers and KCQL and the Connector was verified that properly supports the `.` character in the KCQL configuration. The root cause, was identified to be an issue upstream in Kafka Connect framework